# Can't find used inodes on server

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, inode, df

I have a Xen VPS with Debian Linux installed. Once I found that all inodes are used. I checked this:

```
~# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs         3932160 3932160     0  100% /
udev             59227     262 58965    1% /dev
tmpfs            63251     215 63036    1% /run
/dev/xvda      3932160 3932160     0  100% /
tmpfs            63251       2 63249    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            63251       2 63249    1% /run/shm
```

Then I tryed to find where all inodes were used. Usually them were used by PHP session files (bacause of cron task or PHP internal cleaner were broken). But I can't find what directory contains very large amount of files. I tryed many methods, there is one:

```
/# for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
/aquota.group
1
/aquota.user
1
/bin
124
/boot
9
/dev
264
/etc
1746
/home
1
/initrd.img
1
/lib
4002
/lib64
2
/lost+found
1
/media
1
/mnt
1
/opt
1
/proc
26590
/root
17
/run
214
/sbin
127
/selinux
1
/srv
3
/sys
3609
/tmp
1
/usr
37020
/var
8636
/vmlinuz
1
```

What can I do next?

Comment: Try checking `/proc/*/fd/` for the number of open file descriptors. An open fd may consume an inode without being visible in the file system hierarchy.

Comment: @mpez0 it seems to be good: http://pastebin.com/LHBs071q. And server with this problem (100% used inodes) was rebooted many times.